# Problem with a derivation using the continuity equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, continuity, proof-explanation

Consider the continuity equation for an electron gas:
$$\tag{1}
\nabla \cdot\left[n(\boldsymbol{r}, t) \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tilde{\boldsymbol{r}}(\boldsymbol{r}, t)\right]=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t} n(\boldsymbol{r}, t)
$$
where $\tilde{\boldsymbol{r}}=\boldsymbol{r}_{0} e^{i \boldsymbol{k} r-i \omega t}$ describes the electron position and $n(\boldsymbol{r}, t) \approx n_{0}+n_1(\boldsymbol{r}, t)$ the density of conduction electrons. My professor wrote in his notes that with the following assumptions:
$$\tag{2}
\begin{array}{l}
\left|n_{1}(\boldsymbol{r}, t)\right| \ll n_{0} \\
\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial t} n_{1}(\boldsymbol{r}, t)\right| \ll\left|\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}} \tilde{\boldsymbol{r}}(\boldsymbol{r}, t)\right| \\
\left|\nabla n_{1}(\boldsymbol{r}, t)\right| \ll\left|\nabla \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \tilde{\boldsymbol{r}}(\boldsymbol{r}, t)\right|
\end{array}
$$
The following relation can be obtained from the continuity equation:
$$\tag{3}
\nabla n \approx-n_{0} \nabla\left(\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{\tilde{r}}\right)
$$
However, I really cannot see how that comes about. I have tried to find the connections that show that eq. $(3)$ can be obtained from eq. $(1)$ and $(2)$, but I do not see it.